# How to open Disable Add-ins dialog in Outlook 2010?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, outlook-addin

In Outlook 2013, we can open this dialog by clicking on Manage Add-ins button in File > Info session. But, in Outlook 2010, I cannot do it.

[image]

I still remember I can open this dialog in Outlook 2010 in the first time I install my addins, there is a notify from Outlook, and I click on "View Disable Add-ins..."

But I cannot do it for now.

Any suggestion for me to show this dialog in Outlook 2010?

Answer (score 0):

1.Launch Outlook 2010, and click `File - Options` 
2.Click `Add-Ins` in the navigation pane.
3.There you can see the Disabled Add-Ins

[image]

You can also enable/disable or manually install an add-in by clicking `Disabled Items` and hit `Go..`

[image]

[image]

Comment: This action is not disable an adddin, just inactive it. I tried to do it